# why solution of a second order DE with complex roots does not work when tested?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, homogeneous-equation

For a second order homogeneous DE with complex roots $a \pm bi$ (e.g., $y'' + 6y'+10y = 0$), the solution is:

$$y = e^{ax}(A \cos(bx) + B \sin(bx))$$

When I take the first and second derivative of this solution ($y'$ and $y''$), and put them back into the original DE, it doesn't work, I mean the LHS will not be equal to zero. Is there anything I am missing? why it happens?

Comment: Tip: put a backslash before trig functions (i.e, ```\sin```). It will format it as $\sin$ rather than $sin$

Comment: I'm confused... Usually the "complementary solution" is a particular solution to the non-homogeneous case, so clearly it won't be a solution for the homogeneous case. Can we see the non-homogeneous ODE in question?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes I corrected my question. No need to say complementary.

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DEQ is

$$\tag 1 y'' + 6y'+10y = 0$$

The solution is given by

$$\tag 2 y(x) = e^{-3 x} (a \cos (x)+b \sin (x))$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$

$$(9 e^{-3 x} (a \cos (x)+b \sin (x))-6 e^{-3 x} (b \cos (x)-a \sin (x))+e^{-3 x} (-a \cos (x)-b \sin (x))) + (6 \left(e^{-3 x} (b \cos (x)-a \sin (x))-3 e^{-3 x} (a \cos (x)+b \sin (x))\right)) + (10 e^{-3 x} (a \cos (x)+b \sin (x))) = 0$$

**Update**

$\begin{align} y''(x) &= 6 a e^{-3 x} \sin (x)+8 a e^{-3 x} \cos (x)+8 b e^{-3 x} \sin (x)-6 b e^{-3 x} \cos (x) \\ 6 y'(x) &= -6 a e^{-3 x} \sin (x)-18 a e^{-3 x} \cos (x)-18 b e^{-3 x} \sin (x)+6 b e^{-3 x} \cos (x) \\10 y(x) &= 10 a e^{-3 x} \cos (x)+10 b e^{-3 x} \sin (x) \end{align}$

Now you can easily sum all the items and you get zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is, why LHS is not equal to zero, while we have the correct y? If you simplify LHS, you will get $15e^{-3x}(a\cos(x)+b\sin(x))$.

Comment: I added more details so you can see that the LHS is zero. See it now?

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake now. Thanks for taking the time @Moo.